# Struggling to combine two working functions

Tags: python

I'm new to Python (programming in general) and I've been trying to learn myself through youtube and sites like stackoverflow. In the meantime I've programmed a working trading bot in binance. But now I'm working on a tweak in this bot on the sell part, which I cannot get working. Trying the parameters standalone does work, but when I combine the two it does not work. I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what it is. (It still does buy, but does not sell.)

In the code, on the SELL part, everything works just fine when I change TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL for TRADE_QUANTITY_BUY (so it uses the same value on both buy and sell order).

The sell part does work, when I try this standalone:

```
balance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC')
FREEBTC = float(balance['free'])
TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL = round(FREEBTC, 5) 
#print (TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL)

order = client.create_test_order(
    symbol=TRADE_SYMBOL,
    side=SIDE_SELL,
    type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
    quantity=TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL)
print(order)
```

This is the complete bot version I've tried last. It still does buy, but does not sell.

```
import websocket, json, pprint, talib, numpy
import config
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *

SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btceur@kline_5m"

RSI_PERIOD = 14
RSI_OVERBOUGHT = 70
RSI_OVERSOLD = 30
TRADE_SYMBOL = 'BTCEUR'
TRADE_QUANTITY_BUY = 0.002

closes = []

client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)

balance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC')
FREEBTC = float(balance['free'])
TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL = round(FREEBTC, 6)
#print(SELL_TOTAL)

def order(side, quantity, symbol, order_type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET):
    try:
        print("sending order")
        order = client.create_order(symbol=symbol, side=side, type=order_type, quantity=quantity)
        print(order)
    except Exception as e:
        print("an exception occured - {}".format(e))
        return False

    return True

def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    global closes
    
    print('received message')
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    pprint.pprint(json_message)

    candle = json_message['k']

    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
    close = candle['c']

    in_position = False

    #also tried to put the TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL params here, also does not work

    if is_candle_closed:
        print("candle closed at {}".format(close))
        closes.append(float(close))
        print("closes")
        print(closes)

        if len(closes) > RSI_PERIOD:
            np_closes = numpy.array(closes)
            rsi = talib.RSI(np_closes, RSI_PERIOD)
            print("all rsis calculated so far")
            print(rsi)
            last_rsi = rsi[-1]
            print("the current rsi is {}".format(last_rsi))         

            if last_rsi > RSI_OVERBOUGHT:
                if in_position:
                    print("Overbought! Sell! Sell! Sell!")
                    #put binance order logic here
                    order_succeeded = order(SIDE_SELL, TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL, TRADE_SYMBOL)
                    if order_succeeded:
                        in_position = False
                else:
                    print("It is overbought, but we don't own any. Nothing to do.")

            if last_rsi < RSI_OVERSOLD:
                if in_position:
                    print("Oversold! Buy! Buy! Buy!")
                    #print("It is oversold, but you already own it, nothing to do")
                    order_succeeded = order(SIDE_BUY, TRADE_QUANTITY_BUY, TRADE_SYMBOL)
                    if order_succeeded:
                        in_position = True                  
                else:
                    print("Oversold! Buy! Buy! Buy!")
                    #put binance order logic here
                    order_succeeded = order(SIDE_BUY, TRADE_QUANTITY_BUY, TRADE_SYMBOL)
                    if order_succeeded:
                        in_position = True

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)   

ws.run_forever( )
```

Comment: Since i’m way down, i’ll try a bump.

Answer (score 0):

In the part that works...

```
balance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC')
FREEBTC = float(balance['free'])
TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL = round(FREEBTC, 5) 
#print (TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL)

order = client.create_test_order(
    symbol=TRADE_SYMBOL,
    side=SIDE_SELL,
    type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
    quantity=TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL)
print(order)
```

...the code rounds to a precision of 5 decimal points, while in the code that doesn't work...

```
import websocket, json, pprint, talib, numpy
import config
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *

SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btceur@kline_5m"

RSI_PERIOD = 14
RSI_OVERBOUGHT = 70
RSI_OVERSOLD = 30
TRADE_SYMBOL = 'BTCEUR'
TRADE_QUANTITY_BUY = 0.002

closes = []

client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)

balance = client.get_asset_balance(asset='BTC')
FREEBTC = float(balance['free'])
TRADE_QUANTITY_SELL = round(FREEBTC, 6)
#print(SELL_TOTAL)

# ...
```

...it rounds to a precision of 6 decimal points. `TRADE_QUANTITY_BUY` is at a precision of 3 decimal points; less precise than both. To me, this suggests that perhaps a transaction of lesser than 0.00001 for your particular "coin" at a time is invalid through your API, causing them to be blocked.

My advice: check that the `binance` library you are using supports sell orders of that amount, since sell orders they may be [filtered](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account.html#order-validation).

This all comes from a quick search: this library you are using may have more specific information on minimum/maximum order prices.

Comment: Hey! Thnx for your support. For BTC the max decimals is 6. The standalone part still has 5, but it works with both 5 or max six decimals. The buy part works with this set quantity. I'm trying to sell 'all'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this part

```py
if last_rsi > RSI_OVERBOUGHT:
    if in_position:
```

will ever be `in_position` eq `True`
`in_position = False` is create localy and when `on_message` ends it is still there in python(in some languages may not) but... next time `on_message` is called it will be overriten to `False`
Am I right?

move `in_position = False` to the top and see if it works

Comment: Hey, thnx for your comment. I'll try again, but on one of my first try's (same bot but with a set buy/sell quantity) ```in position = False``` was on top. Then it did not sell. I changed the position to where it is now and it does buy + sell, but i changed the ```in position > True```, because at that time i was in position.  Totally looked over it, thnx!!